# Count number of mergeable commits using git

Tags: linux, bash, git

I have a script that auto merges a feature branch into master. It runs periodically.

I want the script to check that the feature branch does in fact have commits to be merged. If there are no commits the script should exit.

I’ve tried the following:

```
git rev-list --count HEAD
```

Run while on the feature branch called ‘test’ with no commits this is returning a value of 1, so the script doesn’t exit, even though it should because there are no commits to merge.

Note that I ran `git fetch —all` before all of these commands.

Also tried the following:

Tried:

```
git rev-list --count master..
```

Resulted in error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master..': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Tried:

```
git rev-list --count master
```

Resulted in error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Tried:

```
git rev-list --count master..test
```

Resulted in error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master..test': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

How do I determine (from a script) if there are commits to merge?

Comment: Your first issue, as @butsapien noted, is that you don't have a local `master` branch. You seem to have an `origin/master` remote branch, so you can use that instead of `master`.

Comment: The second issue seems to be somewhere between : your  local `test` branch (if you have any ?), your current active commit (`HEAD`) when running the script, and the remote branch `origin/test`.

Comment: 1. can you add to your post the output of `git branch -a`, run from the repo where you try to run your script ? you can reduce the output to the branches (local and remote) named `master` and `test`

Comment: 2. can you post a view of your history `git log --oneline --graph HEAD origin/master origin/test` ? the thing you are looking at locally clearly doesn't match what you are looking from the web ui.

Answer (score 2):

The command you are using is absolutely correct. The error you are seeing in your case means that `master` as a branch is not available in the local file system of the repository from where you are running this command.

To make this work properly, you'd want to put in the right reference.

```sh
git rev-list --count origin/master
```

Assuming that the remote you want to check against, is named `origin`.

Additionally you can do some shell magic to make it work like you want, the below works with `zsh`:

```
# merge branch 
commit_distance=$(git rev-list --count origin/master)
if [ $commit_distance -eq 0 ];
then
  exit 1
fi

# ... the remaining script
```

Comment: The OP is probably looking for `git rev-list --count origin/master..HEAD` or `git rev-list --count origin/master..test`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @bitsapien. I’m almost certain that the branch is available locally, because, as mentioned in the question, I am running `git fetch —all` initially to ensure all the branches are available locally when I run the `git rev-list` command. I’ll check my script again later today.

Comment: @bitsapien I tried the command you suggested, it completes without error, however it returns 1.

Comment: @LeGEC Both the commands you posted completed without error and returned 0.

Comment: @vy218 : ok, could it be that in your current state, `test` is integrated into `master` ?

Comment: @LeGEC However there’s another issue which raises some doubt in my mind as to what the command is actually doing. 

I ran the 2nd command you posted a few more times. After making a commit to test, the command returns 1, after adding another commit to test, the command again returns 1. There are 2 commits in test, so why didn’t it return 2?

Comment: @vy218 Check if there is a merge commit or just a normal one.

Comment: @bitsapien There are just 2 normal commits, when I compare against master branch. Here is the sequence: created branch from master, added file, commit to test, added another file, commit to test.

Comment: @bitsapien : as currently written, your answer will count the count of commits in the complete history of origin/master. You correctly pointed out that the message seen by the OP indicates that `master` doesn't exist, and that he is probably looking for `origin/master`, however the OP also wants to see the commits "in `test` and not in `master`", which would be `origin/master..HEAD` instead of `origin/master` alone.

Comment: @vy218 : post a view of the history of your `test` branch : `git log --oneline --graph test origin/master`, along with the result of `git rev-list --count origin/master..test`

Comment: @LeGEC had some path spec errors running your commands but found this worked: `git log --oneline origin/master..` and that returned only one of the commits. In the web ui a compare of master and test shows 2 commits.

Comment: It’s weird how the command doesn’t return the right number of commits, but for my use case I only need it to return 0 or non zero, and when there were no commits it did return 0, and with more than zero commits it returned non zero. So I’m going to use that command and see how it goes.

Comment: @vy218: it sounds like you might be doing all of these operations in a shallow clone. Are you trying to run these as a Jenkins job?